# Angular material .config not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, themes, angularjs-material

I really don't know what I'm missing, what I'm doing wrong.
These are the libraries included in HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular-material-icons/0.4.0/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
```

I included ng-app in the html tag like so:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

I have this module closure function that declares the module and the config:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('pink')
        .accentPalette('orange');
```

});
  })();

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but if I comment out app.config(..... it works, if not I get an a

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I'm trying to configure a angular material theme. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is the angular material script definitely loading?

Comment: yes, if I remove the config call, everything works. am I missing a library or something?

Comment: I notice you are using a pre release version of material, they are past 1.0 already, how about the latest version, does that still give you the same error?

Comment: I think I'm either missing something from the html , a directive perhaps, or I don't know but it's so annoying. It makes sense I'm doing everything right. I think...

Comment: And that's the only code so far in your angular app? No other modules etc??

Comment: Only code, yes, no modules, still at it, trying v 1.0.6 Something strange is happening, the layout works with dirrectives but it still gives the error and it does not work all the way. Thank you for pointing that out! helped me a bunch! STill at it!

Comment: Well you ought to be able to figure it out from the stack trace leading up to the error to know which module is giving the injector error

Comment: how do I do that exactly?

Comment: If you are using Chrome hit F12 to access developer console and I'd suggest refreshing browser after to regenerate the error. The console will show any errors which usually can be expanded to give further detail including any stack traces of available

Comment: I get this: http://imgur.com/vqgC3lJ It's not much help

Comment: Umm ok, says you are using angularjs 1.5? But your scripts are for 1.3, sure you are not loading in multiple versions by accident somehow?

Comment: my scripts are for 1.3? so this should not work in 1.5.3 ?

Comment: I am not loading multiple  versions by accident. again, if I remove: 

` app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('pink')
      .accentPalette('orange');
  });` 

It works, if not, it gives that annoying error

Comment: @mindparse if I remove $mdThemingProvider from the .config(function($mdThemingProvider) { and all the code inside the function, it works, if I leave $mdThemingProvider  inside the function parameters, it does not.

Comment: ok, this is ridiculous. I can't seem to find the problem. Am I missing a dependency injection? what is going on here? this is dark magic!

Comment: Try referencing non-minified versions of the .js to see if you get a more descriptive error.